# How is ANOVA different from a linear model?

Tags: linear-regression, anova

This may be a naive question, but [I realize all statistical tests of significance are inherently related to linear models](https://lindeloev.github.io/tests-as-linear/) and for anova in particular: I don't exactly understand the difference between it and a regular linear model.

A linear model would already tell you if a predictor has a statistically significant influence on the predicted value right? So then what is anova doing differently? Does it have something to do with the fact that it works with factor predictors?

Comment: In linear regression you assume that $E(y) = X \beta,$ equivalently that $E(y)$ lies in the range (a.k.a. column-space) of $X.$ Anova typically assume that the columns of $X$ are filled with 0 or 1, so is a particular case.